# Giving Application Rights to Change Registry in Windows XP

Tags: c#

I don't have XP on any of my machines.  My efforts to get a small application to run as Administrator in Vista and Windows 7 work.  However one of my testers is reporting that on Windows XP he is getting the following exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ad2' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
```

The code I am using to run the application that tries to write to the registry is:

```
var proc = new ProcessStartInfo {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "ADEFileAssociator.exe"),
                Verb = "runas"
            };

            try {
                Process.Start(proc);
            }
            catch {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to start File Associator", "Process Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
```

This works fine for Vista and Win7 opening the UAC dialog.  If the user accepts to run then the registry is updated on these versions.  I assumed that the same would work for XP.  Clearly I was wrong.  So my question is 'what else do I need to do to get my app to write to the registry in XP?

Comment: Is the user an administrator? If not, there might be nothing he can do to make that registry key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XP you don't have UAC and so you can't use the `runas` verb.  Instead the best you can do is set the `UserName` and `Password` properties of `ProcessStartInfo`.  This pretty much sucks because you'd have to show an authentication dialog or hard code the values!

If I were in your position I'd look very hard for a way to can avoid having to gain admin rights?  If that fails then I'd probably make it a pre-condition for your app to run on XP that the user had admin rights.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish my users would give up XP but some of them hang on like limpets!

Comment: @Scruffy For the life of me I can't understand why you don't use per-user file associations like I already told you. What's more I'm astonished that you are using the `runas` verb instead of using a `requireAdministrator` manifest.

Comment: Because I am still learning and experimenting.  But thankyou for reminding me of the per-user file associations.  Also I have not used manifests before and will take a look - will that solve the issue for XP users?

Comment: no, that just deals with uac which is vista and up. If you do per user there's no need for separate app.

Comment: Thanks - that is what I am looking at now - writing to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes